# Angular 4: Add empty table rows dynamically into table

Tags: angular

I have a table and each td is having a table and it's placed in a component like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of data">
    <td>
        <custom-table [tableData]="row.rec?.observations" [maxLengthArray]="maxLengthArray"></custom-table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <custom-table [tableData]="row.rec?.gaps" [(maxLengthArray)]="maxLengthArray"></custom-table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <custom-table [tableData]="row.rec?.recommendation" [(maxLengthArray)]="maxLengthArray"></custom-table>
    </td>
```

Custom table component is

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr *ngFor="let rec of tableData">
        <td>{{rec}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Component

```
export class CustomTableComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() public tableData: any;
    @Input() public maxLengthArray: number[];
    public tdLeangth: number = 0;

    public ngOnInit() {
      let len = this.maxLengthArray[0] - this.tableData.length;
      while (len === 0) {
          this.tableData.push('');
          len--;
      }
   }
}
```

maxLengthArray is having the max number of rows a custom table component could have and I want to add empty rows to custom table who's count is less than the max length. But each time ngOnInit would get called and only last column is having the empty rows. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by last column is having empty rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do, in the "input" using getter and setter in input

```
_tableData:any
_maxLenghtArray:number[0]
@Input()
  set tableData(value) {
    this._tableData=value;
    if (this._maxLenghtArray)
         this.addRows()
  }
  get tableData()
  {
     return this._tableData;
  }
@Input()
  set maxLenghtArray(value) {
    this._maxLenghtArray=value;
    if (this._tableData)
        this.addRows()

  }
  get maxLenghtArray()
  {
     return this._maxLenghtArray;
  }

addRows()
{
   while (this.tableData.lenght<this.maxLengthArray[0])
       this.tableData.push('');
}
```

Comment: Why do I suppose to call twice in both the Input set methods?

Comment: I don't know if when change a value, (e.g. maxLenghtArray) the other (tableData) has values. I didn't prob the code. try to do only with one of them and tell us if work

Comment: It worked with little modifications. Thank you. However, What if maxLengthArray contains more elements and  I want to loop maxLengthArray, i.e I don't want write it as this.maxLengthArray[0] ? Each row should fill empty rows as per the maxLengthArray[i]

Comment: Really I'll make in component _maxLenghtArray NOT an array (called then maxLength), just a number, and in parent pass the value like < custom-table ...[maxLength]="maxLengthArray[0]">

Comment: If there are 2 sets of rows of maxLengthArray, I have to traverse